# GitLab CI/CD page listing many gitlab runners that no longer exist

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, helm

I am running `GitLab Runner` using a `Helm` chart as described on the [GitLab Runner Helm Chart page](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html).

Everything seems to be working, but after about two months of running I see on my `GitLab` group that controls the `GitLab runner` on the "CI / CD Settings|Runners" page the message

> "Available group Runners: 54".

Here is the first couple on that page:

[image]

Rather than listing all 54 here is the list run through `uniq -c`:

```
      3 gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-9fcb644b9-4f5ss
      2 gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-9fcb644b9-4gqqq
      1 gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-9fcb644b9-889rc
      2 gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-9fcb644b9-grb5j
      1 gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-9fcb644b9-hhv8f
      1 gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-9fcb644b9-kzcdv
     13 gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-9fcb644b9-nvrms
      7 gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-9fcb644b9-pl2k4
      2 gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-9fcb644b9-sxlmp
      9 gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-9fcb644b9-vdmsj
      3 gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-9fcb644b9-vgdnv
      8 gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-9fcb644b9-wst8q
      2 gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-9fcb644b9-xnzhx
```

Looking at my `GitLab Runner` `Kubernetes` container there seems to be only *one* runner:

```
$ /usr/bin/gitlab-runner list
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=4953 revision=1b659122 version=12.8.0
Listing configured runners                          ConfigFile=/home/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner/config.toml
gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-9fcb644b9-grb5j         Executor=kubernetes Token=XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX URL=https://myserver.example.com/
```

Another potentially important piece of information: the `Kubernetes` node that hosts the `GitLab Runner` container is preemptible meaning it gets killed and restarted about every 24 hours.

How do I convince `GitLab` that these old runners are not still around? And how do I avoid this problem in the future?

Answer (score 3):

### Just unregister offline runners:

As per [GitLab Runner commands](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#gitlab-runner-verify) manual:

> To delete the old and removed from GitLab runners, execute the following command.

```
    gitlab-runner verify --delete
```

### You are not alone

P.S. The problem is common: there [are many issues](https://google.com/search?q=site%3A+https%3A%2F%2Fgitlab.com%2Fgitlab-org%2F+issue++intitle%3Arunner+intitle%3Aclean%7Cremove%7Cexpired) with questions like yours.

Moreover, there are several custom recipes to unregister "offline" runners:

- [`bash` script](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/19828#note_54956232)
- [API oneliner with `curl`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/19828#note_132438194)
- [`python` script](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/19828#note_202265652)

### API for "zombie" runners

As [rlandster](https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/10807/rlandster) noted, sometimes you'll need an [API](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/19828#note_132438194)
to unregister "zombie" runners.

```
curl -S --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:<token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/runners/all" | jq '.[] | select(.status == "offline") | .id' | xargs -I runner_id curl -S --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:<token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/runners/runner_id"`
```

This will list all runners, instead of the personal ones: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html#list-all-runners

### P.S. note about runners

Pls note that `Gitlab` itself doesn't manage runners. So, e.g. to restart or shutdown the runner, use appropriate commands on the runner's hosts.

Comment: Running `gitlab-runner verify --delete` does not unregister the "zombie" jobs; the API interface was necessary to do that.